# useState won't update the state when I set it in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I need to render a component that has a route using react router. the first component has a button that when clicked needs to render another component that has state passed in from the first component. The page redirects but doesn't load. All of the data from the first component I want is passed in but it wont set state when I use setProfile(p). All the other console.log()s in the member component show all the data I expect but it won't set the state with this data.

```
import {useLocation} from "react-router-dom";
    const Member = (props)=> {  
      const [user, setUser] = useState({});
      const [profile, setProfile] = useState({});

  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState({});
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [snInstance, setsnInstance] = useState({});
    
   // run effect when user state updates
    useEffect(() => {
  const doEffects = async () => {
    try {
    //  const p = await incidentsInstance.usersProfile(state.user, { from: accounts[0] });
    //  const a = await snInstance.getUsersPosts(state.user, { from: accounts[0] });

      if (state && state.user) {
        setUser(state.user);
      }

      const accounts = await MyWeb3.getInstance().getAccounts();
      setAccounts(accounts);
      console.log(accounts)
      const incidents = MyWeb3.getInstance().getContract(Incidents)
      const incidentsInstance = await MyWeb3.getInstance().deployContract(incidents);
      const sn = MyWeb3.getInstance().getContract(SocialNet)
      const snInstance = await MyWeb3.getInstance().deployContract(sn);
      setsnInstance(snInstance);
      const pro = socialNetworkContract.members[0]
      console.log(pro)
      const p = await incidentsInstance.usersProfile(pro, { from: accounts[0] });
      const a = await snInstance.getUsersPosts(pro, { from: accounts[0] });
      console.log(a)
      console.log(p)
      setProfile(p)

        } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    }
  }
    doEffects();
  }, [profile, state]);

  const socialNetworkContract = useSelector((state) => state.socialNetworkContract)

  return (
    <div class="container">

                <a target="_blank">Name : {profile.name}</a>

        {socialNetworkContract.posts.map((p, index) => {
          return <tr key={index}>
{p.message}
        </tr>})}
      </div>
  )
}

export default Member;
```

This is the parent component I want to redirect from

```
   const getProfile = async (member) => {
        const addr = dispatch({ type: 'ADD_MEMBER', response: member })
        console.log(member)
    }


  const socialNetworkContract = useSelector((state) => state.socialNetworkContract)

    
      return (
          <div>
            {socialNetworkContract.posts.map((p, index) => {
              return <tr key={index}>
    
      <button onClick={() => getProfile(p.publisher)}>Profile</button>
    
            </tr>})}
          </div>
      )
    }
export default withRouter(Posts);
```

I have this component working when I don't have a dynamic route that needs data passing in from the parent component It's redirecting from.

My routes.js looks like

```
const Routes = (props) => {
  return (
      <Switch>

      <Route path="/member" exact component={Member} /> 
        <Route path="/posts" exact component={Posts} />
        <Redirect exact to="/" />
      </Switch>
    
  )
}

export default Routes
```

This is the reducer

```
import { connect, useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
let init = {
    posts:[],
    post:{},
    profiles:[],
    profile:{},
    members:[],
    member:{}
}
export const socialNetworkContract = (state = init, action) => {
    const { type, response } = action;
    switch (type) {
        case 'ADD_POST':
            return {
                ...state,
                posts: [...state.posts, response]
            }
        case 'SET_POST':
            return {
                ...state,
                post: response
            }
        case 'ADD_PROFILE':
            return {
                ...state,
                profiles: [...state.profiles, response]
            }
        case 'SET_PROFILE':
            return {
                ...state,
                profile: response
            }
        case 'ADD_MEMBER':
            return {
                ...state,
                members: [...state.members, response]
            }
        case 'SET_MEMBER':
            return {
                ...state,
                member: response
            }

        default: return state
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make any sense that you would `dispatch({ type: 'ADD_MEMBER', response: member })` with a `member` object that came from the `publisher` property of a `post`.  That info is *already* in your state.  You probably need to be [normalizing your state](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape) better so that you can select it where you need it.

---

You want to use the `Link` component from react-router-dom to navigate to a member's profile page.  Your `Route` should render the correct profile based on an `id` or `username` property in the URL.  Don't pass through the data when you redirect, just go to the correct URL.  On that `Member` page you can get the user from the state by looking up the `id`.

In `Posts`:

```
<Link to={`/member/${p.publisher.id}`}><button>Profile</button></Link>
```

In `Routes`:

```
<Route path="/member/:id" component={Member} />
```

In `Member`:

```
const Member = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  const profile = useSelector((state) =>
    state.socialNetworkContract.members.find((user) => user.id === id)
  );

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const doEffects = async () => {
      if ( ! profile ) {
        dispatch(loadUser(id));
      }
    };
    doEffects();
  }, [dispatch, profile, id]);
```

Comment: Hi thankyou for this answer I will try some of it now. I should have mentioned it's interacting wih a smart contract . each item in the members array is just a string (ethereum address) when the page loads it gets the users data from calling a function in the smart contract and passing in the string as an arguement. The objects returned in  console.log show what they should when the component is redirected to but it never loads up.

Comment: You have `profile` as a dependency of your `useEffect` but you are calling `setProfile` in your effect.  You never want to be updating your dependencies in the effect.

Comment: Is that why it won't work? Where shouuld I setProfile?

Comment: It's hard to say.  Your problem isn't reproducible because your code has missing pieces.  What is `state`?  What is `accounts`? Where is `user` set?  I think your dependencies should be `[user]` but I don't know.

Comment: accounts is a web3 instance of the ethereum address. I have updated my code to include it. the smart contracts send back the variable I want them to. When the page redirects I can all the objects being console.log() in my console.

Comment: You initialize `accounts` to an empty `object` `{}` but you are treating it like an `array` with `accounts[0]`

Comment: FYI the local variable `const accounts` inside the `useEffect` takes precedence over the component state variable `accounts`.  But it's generally not a good idea to repeat names like this because it can be confusing which one you are using.

Comment: When I accounts[0] it returns the correct ethereum address and it works in that component and every other component I call a function on a smart contract

Comment: It calls the contract functions like it's supposed to and the object that is returned is what it is supposed to be but it doesn't set state for the profile variable with the object returned from the smart contract.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230773/discussion-between-linda-paiste-and-john-bradshaw).

Comment: Hi, please could you still help me with this ? I'e been stuck on this one problem for a week. I've updated the question to what I think the problem is to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66989952/how-can-i-initialize-a-react-components-state-from-a-redux-reducer-after-a-redir